# How to add jobs to threadpool with APScheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, apscheduler

I am new to APScheduler
For testing I have set the `max_worker=2` and added 4 different jobs to scheduler. I intended to run 2 jobs in parallel because of the limitation of threadpool, I thought that after finishing certain job another added job will threw into threadpool, but the result below is not what I expected, it just kept running first 2 jobs.

```
Arg is 1, time is Mon Apr 18 19:51:33 2016
Arg is 2, time is Mon Apr 18 19:51:33 2016
No handlers could be found for logger "apscheduler.scheduler"
Arg is 1, time is Mon Apr 18 19:51:37 2016  
Arg is 2, time is Mon Apr 18 19:51:37 2016
Arg is 1, time is Mon Apr 18 19:51:41 2016
Arg is 2, time is Mon Apr 18 19:51:41 2016
Arg is 1, time is Mon Apr 18 19:51:45 2016
Arg is 2, time is Mon Apr 18 19:51:45 2016
...
```

And here is the code:

```
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def job(arg):
    print 'Arg is %s, time is %s' % (arg, time.ctime())
    time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler({'apscheduler.executors.default': {'class': 'apscheduler.executors.pool:ThreadPoolExecutor', 'max_workers': '2'}})
    scheduler.add_job(job, 'interval', seconds=2, args=(1,))
    scheduler.add_job(job, 'interval', seconds=2, args=(2,))
    scheduler.add_job(job, 'interval', seconds=2, args=(3,))
    scheduler.add_job(job, 'interval', seconds=2, args=(4,))

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

Any ways to add remaining jobs to threadpool or something like queue scheme or multiprocessing.dummy.pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jobs which miss scheduled time by any reason are recognized as misfired and these jobs are not launched. In your case jobs are misfired because of lack of free worker. Add parameter `misfire_grace_time=1` (or with another time) to the `add_job` call.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd like to use more than one thread pool executor and limit certain jobs to certain executors?